# Wget: Can I get a pause before reading?

Tags: wget, pause

I'm trying to use [Wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) to download a series of webpages to retrieve the data in them. But when I go to each page after the first, such as:

- `<URL base>&page=2`

the address bar in the browser first shows that URL, then changes to:

- `<URL base>&page=1`

then changes back to the original URL I sent it.

The file downloaded by Wget contains the data for page 1, not page 2. I would like to tell Wget to wait a couple of seconds before starting to download, hoping that it will then retrieve the correct data for page 2.

The [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/) indicates a parameter `--wait`, but this is to get a pause *between* successive retrievals. I need a pause between the time Wget sends the URL and the time it starts downloading the page.

Is that possible?

I'm calling Wget from the Windows command prompt with the following command structure:

```
wget --append-output=<log file name> --show-progress --no-directories --directory-prefix=<output folder name> --adjust-extension --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0" --convert-links --backup-converted --page-requisites --span-hosts "<URL>"
```

I have used this command structure successfully in the past on other websites. If necessary, I can switch to PowerShell. I don't have php, C, etc. on this computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to do is to identify how each *address bar in the browser* change is achieved. This might be done by server sending response with one of [Redirection codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#redirection_messages) which are in range 300...399 or serving page with JavaScript code which do redirect, this can be

```
window.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
```

In order to do so you might use browser, open it then open developer tools (might be named bit different in various browsers, in `chrome` press `F12`) and select network (or similar) then visit page of interest as usual (typing address in bar). Then look for responses status.

GNU `Wget` should cope with first kind (redirect code) but if second kind is used, then you will need another tool, which is able to execute JavaScript (`Wget` is not).

Comment: (1) You say "look for responses status". Are you saying that if I see a response in the 300..399 range, then this indicates the first kind? (2) Can the second kind be detected by finding code in the page like you showed: `window.location.href = ...`? (3) If it's the first kind, you say Wget can cope with it. Can you say how? What would I need to do?

Comment: (1) Yes (2) This is one of possible ways, but there are others (3) set high enough `--max-redirect` value, consult wget [manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wget.1.html) for more data

Comment: The manual says the default of `max-redirect` is 20, which seems like a lot. What are you thinking might be "high enough"?

Comment: @NewSites if your `wget` indeed use `20` for `max-redirect` then it should be enough in most cases, so if it do not provide what you want, then probably there are some JavaScript triggered redirect in pages with which you are working

Comment: Yes, DevTools did show some redirection happening, but on image files, not page files. Also, I found some signs of JavaScript at play. So I guess Wget won't work here. I wrote a script in AutoHotkey to get the page code by copying the outer HTML on the `<HTML>` tag in DevTools, and that worked. I've accepted your answer because I learned useful things from it, even if it didn't solve the specific problem at hand.